# Triggering Pyspark script execution on EMR using AWS Lambda Function

Tags: amazon-s3, pyspark, aws-lambda, amazon-emr

I am trying to run Pyspark script(.ipynb) saved in S3 on EMR cluster Via a lambda function.

def lambda_handler(event, context):
# Initialize AWS clients
s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
#emr_client = boto3.client('emr')
region = 'us-east-1'
emr_client = boto3.client('emr',    region_name=region,aws_access_key_id='*****',aws_secret_access_key='****’)
# S3 bucket and notebook path
s3_bucket = ‘XXXXX’
notebook_key = 's3://XXX/code.ipynb'
# EMR cluster ID
cluster_id = ‘XXX’
# Specify the steps to run
steps = [{'Name': 'Test','ActionOnFailure': 'CONTINUE',  # Define action on failure
'HadoopJarStep': {
'Jar': 'command-runner.jar','spark-submit','--class',    'org.apache.spark.deploy.PythonRunner',
'--deploy-mode', 'cluster', 's3://XXX/pyspark_code.ipynb'
}
}
]

However, I get below error message although I have VPC setup for lambda with outbound rule for port 443
Connect timeout on endpoint URL: "https://elasticmapreduce.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/"

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 34, in lambda_handler
response = emr_client.add_job_flow_steps(JobFlowId=cluster_id, Steps=steps)